# `git rebase` vs `git reset --hard` ... are they the same for deleting the most recent N commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-reset

I understand that, in general, `git rebase -i` and `git reset` are used for very different things.

But in the context of deleting the most recent N commits, it seems to me they are (or can be) identical.  I even did an experiment (with two different local copies of my repository) and as far as I can tell they are the same.  I'm just posting this question in case someone out there can point out where maybe I am missing something.  So here is what I did.

I had a need to remove the most recent 11 commits (never mind why).

I tried two ways of doing it, and they appear to be completely identical; just wondering if I am missing anything in that they are not really identical:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~12`

- **delete** commit lines from the 11 commits that I don't want, keeping only the commit just before them (the one at the top of the interactive rebase file).
- rebase succeeded

2. `git reset --hard HEAD~12`

These two methods appear to have done exactly the same thing.  Is that correct?

Thanks much.  Just trying to understand git a little deeper than I do now.

Comment: Rebasing allows you to do other things too. If you just drop all those commits (either explicitly or by deleting the lines) it's the same as the reset.

Comment: A differentiator is that for `git rebase` one has to edit a file, as mentioned, so, more typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One difference is in their treatment of a dirty tree (files modified but not committed).

`git reset --hard` will trash said changes, while `git rebase -i` will ask you to stash them first.

Answer (score 2):

As 12345ieee points out, the commands behave differently if there are uncommitted change (in the unlikely event that you have uncommitted changes that will still apply after removing the most recent 11 commits); but perhaps you were more interesting in knowing, if all prerequisites are met and the commands both proceed to move the branch pointer, are there any differences in the end state?

In that regard, they are essentially identical.  The entries in the reflogs will record different reasons for what happened, but that's a local (and temporary) concern anyway.

Yet another way to do the same thing:

```
git checkout HEAD~12
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

(This way depends on knowing the branch name; here I've assumed it's `master`.)  And that's without getting into plumbing commands - so really there are even more ways.

It's not really unusual for there to be more than one way to get the same result in git.  The more you understand how git "thinks" about the objects it stores, the easier it becomes to find them.